# Ignore value if it's not close to the maximum

Tags: r

I use the function below to find a "local maximas" in every row of my data:

```
which(diff(sign(diff(Gene name)))==-2)+1
```

but I would like to modify it and set pick only if the other maxima is atleast 20% of the highest value.

That's my data:

```
Name     Mo   Tue   Wen   Thu   Fr   Sat   Sun   
Mark     0     32    53    11    0    33    52   
Ettin    22    51    31    0     0    1      0
Gerard   36    0     13    0    111   33     0   
Marcus   0     44    31    10    0    2      0
```

That's an output I got with my function:

```
Name     Mo   Tue   Wen   Thu   Fr   Sat   Sun   
Mark     0     0     1     0     0    0     1   ## Two local maximas
Ettin    0     1     0     0     0    1     0   ## Two local maximas (Should be one!)
Gerard   1     0     1     0     1    0     0   ## Three local maximas (Should be two!)
Marcus   0     1    0      0     0    1     0   ## Two local maximas (Should be one!)
```

For 3 rows the output isn't correct because the values in cells (Ettin,Sat) & (Gerard, Wen) & (Marcus, Sat) are not even close to atleast 20% of the highest value.

Is it possible to write such function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it (calling your data `mat`)

```
greater <- apply(mat, 1, function(row){
  rowmax <- max(row)
  cutoff <- rowmax * 0.8
  as.numeric(row > cutoff)
})

t(greater)
```

Comment: Nope, that's not what I am looking for. I need to somehow modify the function I posted to cutoff the values which are not atleast 20% of the maximum.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by cutoff?